# Convert Rails 2 relationship into Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

This is my relationship in my modal that I want to convert into rails 4

```
  has_many :members_family, :class_name => 'Patient', :finder_sql => %q(
    SELECT DISTINCT patients.*
    FROM patients
    WHERE id = #{parent_patient_id.to_i} OR parent_patient_id = #{id}
  )
```

I tried like below

```
has_many :members_family, :class_name => 'Patient', -> {where('id = ? or parent_patient_id = ?', parent_patient_id.to_i, id)}
```

but it's not working so please help me.

Comment: Please explain not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic conditions come second, after the association name.  Then the other options.

You will also need to refer to the instance in the block.

```
has_many :members_family, -> (object) {where('id = ? or parent_patient_id = ?', object.parent_patient_id.to_i, object.id)}, :class_name => 'Patient'
```